# Passing result of AsyncTask onwards?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an async task that is executed upon launch:

```
public class BufferApps extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<PackageInfo>> {

PackageManager mPackageManager;
Context mContext;

public BufferApps(PackageManager pm, Context context){
    super();
    this.mPackageManager = pm;
    this.mContext = context;
}

    protected ArrayList<PackageInfo> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        //this code works, not where the problem is

        return installedApps;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PackageInfo> installedApps) {

        ?

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Finished!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening here is I am created an ArrayList of  objects, in particular a list of all apps installed by the user on the device. I think I'm just drawing a blank here but I've been trying this for some time now and can't quite figure it out: the `installedApps` I pass to onPostExecute seems to be ok. So say that `installedApps` is the list described above.

What I want to is to store this list somewhere so that when I need a list of installed apps on my device I can quickly access it without having to do all the hard work of loading the installed apps (the code in doInBackground takes a fair amount of time to execute). How can I do this?

I have tried gson serialization in conjunction with SharedPreference, this raised errors for some reason. I tried creating a separate class with just one ArrayList object that was `static` to contain these entries but this also seemed to fail. I can put up my attempts if necessary but if anyone can just recommend a good way for me to store an ArrayList so that it can be easily accessed by ALL other activities, that would be the most helpful.

Comment: You should have a look to the different options Android provides you with: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: You may be able to use the .get() method from the class which calls your AsyncTask. Such as... BufferApps.execute(); arrayList = BufferApps.get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it in your application class. that is, extend `Application`, and assign that class in your manifest,

```
  <application
      android:name=".MyApplication"
```

now implement your application class like this,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  private final List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

  public void setApps(List<App> apps) {
    this.apps = apps;
  }

  public List<App> getApps() {
    return apps;
  }
}
```

in your `onPostExecute()`, call,

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).setApps(apps);
```

anytime you need the apps from any other component, call,

```
List<App> apps = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getApps();
```

you still need to consider the complexity of what you do when the apps list is not yet available. for that, you could

1. create your own callback interface ... e.g., instead of calling `getApps()` and taking the return result, you call `getApps()` and pass in a callback. the implementation of `getApps()` then either calls the callback immediately if it has it, or starts the `AsyncTask` and calls the callback in `onPostExecute()`.
2. just return null from `getApps()` if it's not available, and start the `AsyncTask`. when the task finishes, broadcast an intent which indicates the apps are now available. interested callers must register for the intent and handle it appropriately.